# Google Script Timestamps onChange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script to copy values from `Column C` to the `Next Blank Column` -- however, I would like to use a separate timestamp script to add the date (`MM yyyy`) in `Row 1` of the same column being changed. [See [Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing)]

(For example, the first time my 'copy values' function runs, it will copy values in `C2:C16` to `D2:D16` ... I would like to then automatically place a timestamp with format `MM yyyy` in cell `D1` -- then, next month, it will copy `C2:C16` to `E2:E16` and I'd like `MM yyyy` placed in `E1`, and so on.)

The below script is working to timestamp above a cell when I edit it, but fails to timestamp when I run my other script.

```
function onEdit() {
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if( r.getColumn() >= 4 && r.getColumn() <= 20) { //checks the column
        var nextCell = r.offset(-1, 0);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
      }
    }
```

I have tried changing it to an `onChange` function, with no success.

any help is def. appreciated!

TY!

and here is the `Copy Values` function mentioned above:

```
function readSalesNum() {
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

// Copy from 17th row, 4th column, all rows for one column 
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 3, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//Paste to another sheet from first cell onwards
sheetTo.getRange(2,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on how the `copyValues()` function is invoked & how it calls this `onEdit()` function? I suspect the problem is that `r` is out of range.

Comment: adding `copyValues` function above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onEdit()` function is not being called when you run `readSalesNum()` because the onEdit() trigger runs only on edits made by a ***user***. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit):

> **onEdit()**
>
> The onEdit() trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value
>   of any cell in a spreadsheet.

A better option would be to put the timestamp into its own function that you can call at the end of `readSalesNum()` as well as with a trigger. Or you could just add the timestamp at the end of `readSalesNum()`. Also, why not use `Utilities.formatDate()` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))) to create pre-formatted timestamp, as it appears that you're relying on cell formatting for your timestamp format?

e.g. (just adding a timestamp)

```
function readSalesNum(){
  ... your code ...
  sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "your_timezone", "MM yyyy")); 
}
```

Comment: That's a thought I had, but could use a hand making it happen

Comment: Hopefully the example will help.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Dean!